# Get part of LineString with specific distance from starting point

Tags: python, shapely

I have a LineString AB and a Point C which lies on the LineString AB.
I need measure out specific distance (say, 10 meters) along LineString AB either side of the point C and get resulting LineString DE.

[image: pic]

Comment: And the line always has only two vertices?

Comment: @Mayo LineString AB may be curved (e.g. border of a Polygon)

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62990029/how-to-get-equally-spaced-points-on-a-line-in-shapely.

Comment: @user30184 thanks. I saw this post. I did not understand how to specify the given point C as the starting point.

Comment: I do not know really. Does shapely have a function like line_locate_point in SpatiaLite https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html?